# Is there a way to change the default camera app launched from the iOS5 lock screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera

In iOS 5 the lock screen can access the camera app.

Is there a way to change the default app that is launched. I would rather use instagram for its social media connections and filters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, but Apple doesn't allow this, and it doesn't even look like there is a jailbreak tweak for this.

Comment: Sadly, after more extensive research, you're right.

Comment: Bummer...that would be a nice feature to have, but I don't see Apple doing anything official about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are runnning a jailbroken iOS5 device, [AnyLockApp](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=anylockappDp) seems to be able to change the default app.

You will have to enter your passcode in order to use the app though.

Comment: no I am using iOS5

Comment: Did you read the description of the app? It only works for IOS5 or higher.

Comment: No, I am running iOS5 not a Jailbroken device.

Comment: iOS5 and a jailbroken device are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Having said that, I don't think there will ever be a way to change the app unless the overlords at Apple say so.

Comment: correct, like I say, I am not going to Jailbreak my device.

Comment: It wasn't clear in the question that this was going on a device that was not to be jailbroken, so I thought it was an appropriate answer. I'm just going to leave the answer here anyway.

Comment: that's fine, as others may need it.

Comment: This was perfect, thanks!  And Graeme, the only downside to jail breaking is having to do a little more work to upgrade each time.  It's great for this sort of thing.